# Skype and Google+ on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, skype, google-plus

I am thinking about installing Ubuntu 13.10 in my computer, but I am afraid because I must use vídeo chat with Skype... I've seen few pictures of someone's image using Skype, but does it really work easily? And what about Google+?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience skype works pretty well without issue. If you want to use google's version you can download the chrome browser for linux here: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/?platform=linux

Answer (score 0):

Skype work flawless in Ubuntu.

you can download & install it with

```
wget http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
```

If you get any unmet dep's

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

thats it.It will install Skype in your Ubuntu.

Google+ and hangouts are works flawlessly with Firefix , Google Chrome, chromium. you can use any of these browsers.